# Why does TypeScript allow to compile?

Tags: typescript

There are two simple TypeScript codes.

a.ts

```
console.log(name);
```

b.ts

```
console.log(a);
```

a.ts can be compiled, but compiler complains for b.ts

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc a.ts
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc b.ts
b.ts(1,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'a'.
```

Why can a.ts be succeeded?
I'm really confused.

I'm using v2.0.10

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 2.0.10
```

Best,

Comment: Perhaps 'name' is a variable that exists in the global scope?

Comment: `window.name` is a predefined property giving the name of the window.

Comment: Depending on how smart your IDE is, it is likely to be able to tell you where `name` is coming from. In vscode, for example, it shows me the declaration `declare var name: string;` in `lib.d.ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the following code in Chrome developer tools

```
for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}
```

You'll see a property "name" (in the case of a Web Browser, the global scope is the window).

So the TypeScript compiler allows you to reference 'name' (what would otherwise be an undeclared variable) because it knows that it exists on window (the global scope). Whereas there is no property 'a' in the global scope, so the compiler is doing its job and telling you about it.

Comment: But to be precise, the TS compiler does not introspect the contents of the `window` object at compile time. Thus, a better answer would show where in what typings file the `window.name` property is declared so that TS knows about it, and would also point to the documentation for the `window.name` global property.

Comment: @eddiewould and torazaburo Thanks! I will be careful with names in window. I started using typescript on node, so I didn't think about window properties of browser :)